# Dynamically added radio button does not act like a different group

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have the following radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" class='form-control' name="progress_type[]" value="Journal Papers"><span class='radio-label'>Journal Paper</span>
<input type="radio" class='form-control' name="progress_type[]" value="Conference Proceeding"><span class='radio-label'>Conference Proceeding</span>
<input type="radio" class='form-control' name="progress_type[]" value="Conference Presentation"><span class='radio-label'>Conference Presentation</span>
```

I want to add another block of radio group, with the same name value so that in PHP I can get an array of selected values.

I am adding the next radio button  group with the following jQuery code

```
$(this).parent().prepend('<p class="help-block">Type</p><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="progress_type[]" value="Journal Papers"><span class="radio-label">Journal Paper</span><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="progress_type[]" value="Conference Proceeding"><span class="radio-label">Conference Proceeding</span><input type="radio" class="form-control" name="progress_type[]" value="Conference Presentation"><span class="radio-label">Conference Presentation</span><p class="help-block">Details</p><input type="text" class="form-control input-margin" name="progress_pub[]">');
```

It adds but when I test, I can only select 1 radio button out of 6. Although I thought I can choose 2 different values from the two different radio button groups.

Please note that I dont know how many radio button groups users will create.

Should I use two dimensional arrays?

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: you should use `checkboxes` instead of radio buttons for your requirement. `radio` element can be selected on ly one while `checkboxes` can be selected multiple.

Comment: but in each group of 3, only one value should be selected. so i am sure i should use radio buttons. But I expected it should be array of values because of the name value has []. But it is not. It acts like a single radio button group. @BrijeshBhatt

Comment: Radio button groups are defined by the name. It doesn't matter whether they're added statically or dynamically -- if they have the same name, they're the same group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `progress_type[]` as the names for your radio buttons, use `progress_type[id]`, where you replace `id` with the index of that section of the form.

Then when you're processing the parameters, you can use `$_POST['progress_type'][$id]` to get that block's selection.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different `name` property for your different groups.  So `progress_type[]` will be the name of your first group, and perhaps `progress_type_2[]` will be the name of your second.  If this was part of a form, it's the `name` property that you will use to access the different answers.  (That being said, you probably don't want to add the array brackets to the ends of your names -- it is enought to call them `progress_type` and `progress_type_2`).

Comment: But adding array brackets without indicating their indexes or without giving different name values works fine with text inputs, why not with the radio buttons? I am still guessing there should be better way to handle this..

Comment: Brackets only does what you want when you can fill in multiple elements with the same name. Radio buttons don't work that way, because you can only select one of them.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But if i named them the way you suggested, i think i would have some issues retrieving them after submitting the post :) because i dont know how many radio button groups the user will create..

Comment: It works fine because any string will be a legal identifier.  I mentioned that because in some backend tools, you can go at your answer like so:  `forms[0].progress_type`.  It's not a requirement, but it is a good habit.

Comment: The way to handle this is to keep another hidden input.  You will put the number of radio groups into that input's value.  On the backend, you will have to read its value by constructing the string: `"progress_type_" + index`.  By using arrays the way you have, you aren't really saving anything (you will still have to concat), and it's a bit strange looking.

Comment: Since I kind of understand what you are going for, maybe a compromise is to name the first `progress_type[0]` and second `progress_type[1]`.  You'll still need concat to build the name on the backend (i.e., `"progress_type[" + index + "]"`, but maybe it feels more comfortable for you.  That aside, hopefully you see that the only problem here is that your names were chosen to be the same, and html doesn't like that.